# How can I simplify a definite integral raised to a power? $\bigg(\int_a^bf(t)dt\bigg)^n$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Is there a way to simplify and integral to some power into a single integral?
$$\bigg(\int_a^b{f(t)}dt\bigg)^n=\int_c^dg(t)dt$$
My first thought was to rewrite the integral as
$$\int_a^b\int_a^b...\int_a^bf(t_1)f(t_2)...f(t_n)dt_1dt_2...dt_n$$
and use the Cauchy formula for repeated integration to collapse it into
$$\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_a^b(b-t)^{n-1}f(t)dt$$
but I realized that only works for repeated antidifferentiation -  not definite integration.
$$$$$$$$
The problem arose because I was looking to find for what values of b
$$\sin\bigg(-b{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\ln(t)e^{-t}dt\bigg)=0$$
I thought it might help rewrite it as a mclaurin series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg[\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}(-b{\pi})^{2n+1}\bigg(\int_0^{\infty}\ln(t)e^{-t}dt\bigg)^{2n+1}\bigg]=0$$
and I was planning to rewrite the sum to be
$$\int_c^d\bigg[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}g(t)\bigg)\bigg]dt=0$$

Is there any way to do this?
Less importantly - is there a good way to evaluate the sum in the resulting integral?

edit: I'm specifically looking for integer values of b

Comment: Even for the simple step function case, writing $(f_1+f_2+\cdots +f_m)^n$ as a sum requires $\binom{n+m-1}{n}$ terms. And there doesn't appear to be a natural linear order to the terms of that sum. I doubt this is possible.

Comment: The expression you give as a multivariate integral is really the only thing available. There's no further simplification unless $f(t_1) \dots f(t_n)$ happens to have a particularly nice form, which does happen sometimes. As for your motivation, $\int_0^{\infty} (\ln t) e^{-t} \, dt$ is just some fixed real number $r$ so isn't the answer just $b = \frac{k}{r}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$? Why use a Taylor series when we know exactly when the sine of some number is zero?

Comment: The integral evaluates the Euler's constant: $\int\limits_0^\infty dt \ e^{-t}\ln(t)=-\gamma$. So the values of $b$ you seek are $b_n=n/\gamma$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @qiaochu-yuan I should have said this in the original post but I'm looking specifically to see if there are any integer values of b. I used the taylor series hoping it might help me see if such a value of b can exist.

Comment: Integrate from index $2$ to $n$.

Comment: @Julia: given Sal's comment, this is an open problem. It's equivalent to asking whether $\gamma$ is irrational.

Comment: There is no way to simplify that expression in the title, and we don't know if Euler's constant is rational or irrational. May I ask why you are interested in integer b-values?
(+1) for effort

Comment: @phi-rate I was interested in integer b values because they're existence or inexistence would prove the rationality of Euler's constant. I didn't think I'd find anything but I wanted to try anyway.